# How can we inject a DAO dynamically

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa

Is it possible to inject a DAO dynamically, I mean to say inject aDao if the param value is "a" or inject bDao if the param value is "b". I know we can inject both the DAO's and use it as per the what param is passed. I was just wondering if it is possible to influence which DAO or bean is injected at run time.

Ravi

Comment: I don't understand the question. Show us some code.

Comment: are talking about spring's dependency injection?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about CDI dependency injection (as your question is tagged with java-ee), `Qualifiers` is the solution you're looking for.

See http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html

Comment: If it is the case please replace JPA tag by CDI one